# Resize UIViewController instead of removing it from navigation stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

user navigate from **VC-A --> VC-B**. Then when user wants come back to **VC-A , VC-B** should resize and stay on top. i tried of resizing the **VC-B** but doesn't bring **VC-A** to appear.

Comment: Add a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve of what you've tried already.

Comment: You are viewing `VC-A`, want to show `VC-B`, and then want to "resize" `VC-B` so it only partially covers `VC-A`?

Comment: @DonMag, yes, but please dont suggest me container view

Answer (score 1):

If both ViewController A and B are children of a `UINavigationController`, then you should consider pulling them out of this structure, because the UINavigationController will play by its own rules; A can be unloaded when it is not visible (e.g. when B is presented on top of it), and navigating back from B to A will pop B from the navigation stack.

Comment: I am using ContainerView in VC-B, so it must stay on Navigation Controller

Comment: Thanks, i did it using different way instead of adding on navigation stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you are viewing **VC-A**, want to show **VC-B**, and then want to "resize" **VC-B** so it only partially covers **VC-A**...

You cannot do that within a Navigation Controller.

What you'll want to do is add **VC-B** as a child `UIViewController` and add its view as a subview of **VC-A**'s view (covering it completely).

Then, instead of *going back to **VC-A***, you will resize/reposition **VC-B**'s view so it is only partially covering **VC-A**'s view.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with a `UIViewController` 
Try to recreate your **VC-B** as a child view of **VC-A** and set a height and width constraint of your child view in your **VC-A** so that you can control the position and visibility of the child view from your **VC-A**